# Force UITextView to render text on demand?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a `UITextView` as a log for some operations that I'm starting when a `UIButton` is clicked. However, the `text` property of `UITextView` when changed, doesn't get rendered as and when it's updated. The whole list of log text gets displayed only as the `IBAction` for the `UIButton` returns.

Is this actually possible or should I be looking at some other UI object to this?

Edited to add example code below:

```
var log: UITextView!
IBAction func runOps() {
 self.log += "Starting ops..."

 self.log += "Starting ops1.."
 self.ops1()
 self.log += "ops1 completed.."

 self.log += "Starting ops2.."
 self.ops2()
 self.log += "ops2 completed.."
}
```

Comment: I did a quick test with a `UITextView` by using multiple ```dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  self.textView.text = @"a";
 });```
with different times and the `UITextView` gets updated on screen.

So this leads me to believe that something with where you are setting the `UITextView` text is not quite right.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I'll give the `dispatch_after` method a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can try to use NotificationCenter.

[image]

Comment: I'll take a look at this one if the `dispatch_after` method suggested doesn't work. I'm looking for something simple like "flush" the added text or changing some property. But, thanks for the idea.